# Cython Performance

Tags: python, cython

Problem: I have 3 numpy array of 2 dimensional.
Need to apply correction based on image segments it belongs to.
Indexes for the image is being taken from image 2

```
def correction(image1: ndarray, image2: ndarray,image3: ndarray, segments: List[int],
                        params: correctionParams) -> ndarray:
    correct_image = np.array(image1)
    for segment in segments:
        correction_line = params.correction.get(segment) // List of float values
        image3_mask = image3== segment // Get  mask of true/false to  focus on specific type of rows\col
        segment_values = np.take(correction_line, image2[image3_mask ]) //Take specific indicies value
        correct_image [image3_mask ] = image1[image3_mask ] * segment_values //apply correction
    return correct_imag
```

It takes 4 seconds for 4K * 4k  numpy array for 5 iterations.

I am trying to speed by by cython but could not get better performance.
Cython pyx code

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef correction(np.ndarray[dtype_t,ndim=2,mode='c'] image1, np.ndarray[dtype_t,ndim=2,mode='c'] image2,np.ndarray[dtype_t,ndim=2,mode='c'] image3, segments: List[int],
                        params: GradeCorrectionParams) :
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2, mode='c'] correct_image = np.array(image1)

    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim = 2, mode = 'c'] image3_mask 
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, mode='c'] segment_values = np.empty((4000))
 
    for segment in segments:
        grade_correction_line = params.grade_correction.get(segment)
        image3_mask = np.array(image3== segment,dtype=bool)
        segment_values = np.take(grade_correction_line, image2[image3_mask ])
        correct_image [image3_mask ] = image1[image3_mask ] * segment_values 
    return correct_image `
```

Both gave same performance.I  wanted to get suggestions how to optmize via cython.
Tried to implement Take operation in cython but it gave bad performance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Code Review

Comment: I don't think "suitable for code review" has ever implied off-topic here